# Overloading constructor at child invalidates overloaded constructors at parent in swift

Tags: swift, constructor, overloading

I have class Parent like this:

```
class Parent {
    init? (data: AnyObject) { }
}
```

I have class Child like this:

```
class Child : Parent {
    init? (info: AnyObject) { }
}
```

When I write code like this:

```
let obj = Child (data: someData);
```

I get error:

`Incorrect argument label in call (have 'data:', expected 'info:')`

But if I remove the constructor at child, the error disappears.

How can I have both of the constructors at child? Thanks.

Comment: Read the [Initializer Inheritance and Overriding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID221) section of the Swift book.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31459131/1226963 for your answer.

Comment: Oh ok I get it now. Thanks!