# override initializer from generic class

Tags: swift, generics, initializer

```
open class CheckItem<T, U: Equatable & CustomStringConvertible>: DataTableItem<T,U,Bool> {
    public override init(_ data: T, getter: @escaping (T) -> U) {
        super.init(data, getter: getter)
    }
}

open class DataTableItem<T, U: Equatable & CustomStringConvertible, V: CustomStringConvertible>: TableItem{
    let data: T
    let getter: (T) -> U

    public init(_ data: T, getter: @escaping (T) -> U) {
        self.data = data
        self.getter = getter
    }
}

open class TableItem: NSObject {
    public var title: String?
}
```

It is weird that, can't override the init in subclass CheckItem.

Compiler complains that Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass. It complains that Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword if I remove the override keyword.

It drives me crazy anyone helps? Thanks in advance.

The more weird part is that it works in LabelItem

```
open class LabelItem<T, U: Equatable & CustomStringConvertible, V: CustomStringConvertible>: DataTableItem<T,U,V>{

public override init(_ data: T, getter: @escaping (T) -> U) {
    super.init(data, getter: getter)
}
```

The full code is available here https://github.com/magerate/TableMaker

**Edit**

```
let checkItem = CheckItem<People, Bool>(people, getter: {(p: People) -> Bool in
        p.isGirl
    })
```

It compiles if don't try to create any instance of CheckItem. But complains

> Cannot convert value of type 'People' to expected argument type 'Bool'

when try to create a new instance of CheckItem.

It seems that type inference is not correctly here.

**Edit**

It works when I deploy the code to swift framework. WTF

Comment: Can you show `TableItem`  class?

Comment: TableItem don't define any initializer

Comment: @Andrew,

I copy+pasted your code into a playground (and added properties for `data` and `getter`.  I am able to create an instance of `CheckItem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly goes wrong for you. When I run your code everything seems fine. Are you sure you're instantiating your instances correctly?

```
let checkItem = CheckItem("Check item data") { (string: String) -> String in
    return string + "checkItem"
}


let labelItem = LabelItem<String, String, Int>("Label item") { (string: String) -> String in
    return string + "labelItem"
}


let dataTableItem = DataTableItem<String, String, Int>("Data table item") { (string: String) -> String in
    return string + "dataTableItem"
}
```

In `LabelItem` and `DataTableItem` you have a generic `V` which is not used anywhere and is not a parameter, so you need to be explicit with your types upon instantiation since you're not passing the `V` type in the init and the compiler can't infer the type. Thus `<String, String, Int>` or any other types that meet the constraints.

**EDIT:**

After looking into your project code (the project didn't run on my Xcode, I only copied relevant code into my project) I still see no problem - both initializers of `CheckItem` compile:

```
open class TableItem: NSObject {
    public var title: String?
}

open class DataTableItem<T, U: Equatable & CustomStringConvertible, V: CustomStringConvertible>: TableItem{
    let data: T
    let getter: (T) -> U

    public weak var host: TableItemHost?

    public init(_ data: T, getter: @escaping (T) -> U) {
        self.data = data
        self.getter = getter
    }
}

public protocol TableItemHost: class {}

open class CheckItem<T, U: Equatable & CustomStringConvertible>: DataTableItem<T,U,Bool> {
    public init(_ data: T, host: TableItemHost, getter: @escaping (T) -> U) {
        super.init(data, getter: getter)
        self.host = host
    }

    public override init(_ data: T, getter: @escaping (T) -> U) {
        super.init(data, getter: getter)
    }
}
```

Creating instances:

```
let checkItem1 = CheckItem("Check item 1 ") { (string: String) -> String in
    return string
}

class Host: TableItemHost {}
let host = Host()
let checkItem2 = CheckItem("Check item 2 ", host: host) { (string: String) -> String in
    return string
}

print(checkItem1.data)
print(checkItem2.data)
```

Copy paste my code into a playground and see for yourself. Perhaps there is something other than the initializer causing the error.

For a test you can also try commenting out both initializers of `CheckItem` and instantiate it with the inherited initializer. That should work, because `CheckItem` will not have its own designated initializer anymore (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31459131/1433612)

Comment: Hello Au Ris, the code is available here https://github.com/magerate/TableMaker, if I uncomment the initializer in CheckItem, it can build succeeded and works well.

Comment: The project didn't run for me I am still using Xcode 9.2, my guess you used 9.3. But I looked the code and I don't see the problem with `CheckItem` initializers.

Comment: Try running the code I added in my edited answer in a playground and confirm that it works. If yes, look for the problem somewhere else not in that initializer.

Comment: The code you added works in playground. It even works in TextFieldItem in the same project.