# Subclassing `MKMapItem` resulting in Fatal error

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, mapkit

I would like the `MKMapItem` returned from `MKLocalSearch` to contain an "altitude" property. In order to achieve this, I've decided to create a subclass for `MKMapItem`.

```swift
class MapItemGeoSpatial: MKMapItem {
    var altitude: Measurement<UnitLength>
    
    public init(placemark: MKPlacemark, altitude: Measurement<UnitLength>) {
        self.altitude = altitude
        super.init(placemark: placemark)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

While the above implementation compiles, it results in a fatal error when attempting to initialise `MapItemGeoSpatial`.

```
Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class 'MapItemGeoSpatial'
```

The above error occurs during the `super.init(placemark: placemark)` call.

I can create an `override init()` for the above class, but this will require me to initialise the `altitude` property, which is not specified for this initialiser. Initialising `altitude` by specifying a dummy variable (eg. `0`) overcomes this issue, but appears to be a poor workaround. Making `altitude` optional is another workaround, but this is not a direction I wish to take.

I'm aware that `MKMapItem` inherits from `NSObject` and I'm curious if this relation has an influence on the above observation. I would like to i) understand the root cause behind this issue and ii) determine if subclassing `MKMapItem` is a viable solution to the problem mentioned at the start of this post.

Comment: Apologies as I did not mention this, but altitude is set by me (the source of this value is not relevant to this discussion, but it is determined by extracting the coordinates from `MKMapItem`) via the designated initialiser `. As such, I understand that `MKLocalSearch` has nothing to do with altitude, but I, as the client, found it desirable to contain this information when it is passed to other areas of my project. This is the primary reason why I chose to subclass `MKMapItem`, in an attempt to "inherit" all it's functionality and introduce my own functionality.

Comment: The flow diagram for this process is- `MKLocalSearch` -> `MKMapItem ` -> Determine altitude using coordinates from `MKMapItem` -> Initialise `MapItemGeoSpatial`

Comment: You don't need to subclass in that case. You can just wrap it.

Comment: Right I see- so just encapsulate `MKMapItem` within `MapItemGeoSpatial`? Yep that's a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

[@matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt)'s comment suggests to wrap `MKMapItem`, which is a viable solution for the original question.

For those interested in the reason behind the crash, I posted the [same question](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/704990) in the Apple Developer Forum, and one of the [comments](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/704990?answerId=711755022#711755022) suggested a potential cause. I'll summarise it in this post.

The below diagram represents the general overview for the initialisation process in Swift (see [Class Inheritance and Initialization](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID216) for more information). Take note that designated initialisers can not invoke convenience initialisers from the superclass.
[image: Swift Subclass Initialisation]

The process for subclassing an Objective-C object (eg. `MKMapItem`) in Swift however does not follow the above convention. In particular-

1. Objective-C allows a [convenience initialiser of a superclass to be invoked from a subclass](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/783584/Subclassing-Objective-C-classes-in-Swift-and-the-p)
2. Objective-C classes automatically inherit superclass initialisers (Swift requires [certain conditions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html) to be met for this to occur)

`MapItemGeoSpatial` from the original question does not meet the [requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31459131) from the second point above to inherit the superclass initialisers. In addition, `MKMapItem.init(placemark:)` appears to be a convenience initialiser as it invokes `MKMapItem.init()` internally (see point 1. on why `MapItemGeoSpatial` can call it from the designated initialiser).

The below diagram attempts to visualise the above.

[image]

## Disclaimer

I do not use Objective-C and I don't have a good foundation in the language. The above findings are based on observations and the information gathered from the specified resources. I would appreciate if someone with a better understanding of Objective-C and Swift provides a more detailed explanation or specifies any corrections.